# How do I permanently disable the APM (advanced power management) of my Hitachi hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hdparm

I'm using [quietHDD](https://sites.google.com/site/quiethdd/) and/or [hdparm](http://disablehddapm.blogspot.com/) to disable [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Power_Management) on my very clicky Hitachi hard drives (to stop the disk heads from parking).

The program supposedly only needs to be run at boot time and after power cycles such as standby/sleep. However, in my case it seems to only work for short periods at a time before the clicking returns and I have to run quietHDD or hdparm again.

Is there a way to *permanently* edit the drives' settings so APM is completedly disabled for the life of the drive?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the [Hitachi Feature Tool](https://www.hgst.com/support/hard-drive-support/downloads/legacy-downloads#FeatureTool), if it works with your drive. But there is no information whether your warranty will still be valid after changing the APM value. That's why I asked [my question about the warranty here](https://superuser.com/questions/1273406/can-hitachi-feature-tool-void-the-warranty-by-changing-the-apm-value-of-hdd) and found your question accidentally.